# Seeking some clarification on use of <g:javascript>

Tags: javascript, grails

I understand the one of the reasons why the `<g:javascript>` tag is used is to specify which AJAX library we want to use, such as when we use it like this `<g:javascript library="jquery"/>`. But then I've also seen this tag used with static resources such as when it is use like this:

```
<g:javascript src="hello.js"/>
<g:javascript src="goodbye.js"/>
```

So then my questions becomes, what advantageous functionality does it provide when is is used on static resources? In other words, what are the exact differences between its usage on static resources vs say doing it like this:

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<script src="goodbye.js"></script>
```

? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a bit of research into what the tag library does will uncover some notes about what it does beyond the standard script tag.

For instance the [API documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/JavascriptTagLib.html#javascript) states the following:

> The 'src' attribute will merely import the js file but within the
>   right context (ie inside the /js/ directory of the Grails application:

```
<g:javascript src="myscript.js" /> // actually imports '/app/js/myscript.js'
```

The tag library also allows you to specify what plugin, context path, and library to use for your included javascript. It also supports inline javascript.

Hope that helps you understand why it exists, and what it offers. All of this is also in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for that good explanation. Of the links your provided, the first one, is that to the old documentation or something? Seems like good stuff.

Comment: It's a link to the API documentation, which documents the actual classes within Grails. It's a few minor versions back but still relevant as I don't recall that tag library has changed much since 1.4/2.0.